# Microsoft Graph - what is 'Users.Read.All' Permission scope?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

According to the documentation here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_workingwith

List working with needs a permission scoe of `Users.Read.All`, but I can't find it here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

Is that a typo and meant to read `User.Read.All` instead? without the plural? Or something else entirely?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a typo, thank you for catching it :). The scope is User.Read.All.